# Notification when a R process is finished [iTerm2]

Tags: r, triggers, notifications, iterm2

I'm running *R* within a HPC and I'd like to be notified when a long running process is finished (within R terminal, not as a Rscript).

I know the way to do it is through [triggers](https://iterm2.com/documentation-triggers.html) but I have no idea how to... any idea, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simpler what I thought, but as anyone didn't answer, here there's my (posible) solution:

1. Write a simple function called fin(): `fin <- function(){print("fin")}`
2. Then go to *Preferences > Profiles > Advanced > Triggers* and add a new trigger based on function's output: *Regular expression* = `\[1\] "fin"`, *Action* = *Post Notification*... et voilá!